# Passing properties to a function pipeline output error

Tags: function, powershell, csv, export-to-csv, pipeline

I'm getting this error when I add to the return the `-prefix "File_Name"` to the end of `Return $Results | Out-Excel -Prefix "File_Name"` if I leave `-prefix "File_Name"` off of the script it works. What am I missing?

```
Out-Excel : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of 
the parameters that take pipeline input.
At \\util01\cs\Scripts\PowerShell\BradleyDev\Google Chrome\Set-Chrome-Service-ON-V3.ps1:52 char:21
+ } Return $Results | Out-Excel -Prefix "File_Name"
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (@{PC=CD-100TRAINER; Status=OFF-LINE}:PSObject) [Out-Excel], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Out-Excel
```

---

```
foreach ($PC in $Process){
$counter ++
$Service = "gupdate"
$State = "delayed-auto"
$command = "sc.exe \\$PC config $Service start= $State"
$count = $Process.Count
$command2 = "sc.exe \\$PC config gupdatem start= demand"
if (test-connection -computername $PC -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -quiet) {
    $Output = Invoke-Expression -Command $Command -ErrorAction Stop
    $Output = Invoke-Expression -Command $Command2 -ErrorAction Stop
    if($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0){
       Write-Host "$counter of $count : $PC : Failed More details: $Output" -foregroundcolor White -BackgroundColor RED
       $status = [string]$Output
    } else {
       Write-Host "$counter of $count : $PC : Success" -foregroundcolor DarkGreen
       $status = "Success"
    }
} else {
    Write-Host "$counter of $count : $PC : OFF-LINE" -foregroundcolor black -BackgroundColor gray
    $status = "OFF-LINE"
}       
$PCobject = [PSCustomObject] @{
    PC = $PC
    Status = $status
}
$Results +=$PCobject
} Return $Results | Out-Excel -Prefix "File_Name"
```

---

```
function Out-Excel {
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,HelpMessage="Enter Prefix",ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
    [string[]]$Prefix = $null,
    $Path = "$env:temp\$Prefix`_$(Get-Date -Format yyMMdd_HHmmss).csv"
)
$input | Export-CSV -Path $Path -UseCulture -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
Invoke-Item -Path $Path
} #end function
```

Updated but still failing:

```
function Out-Excel {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,HelpMessage="Enter Prefix")]
        [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
        [string[]]$Prefix = $null,
        $Path = "$env:temp\$Prefix`_$(Get-Date -Format yyMMdd_HHmmss).csv"
    )
    $input | Export-CSV -Path $Path -UseCulture -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
    Invoke-Item -Path $Path
} #end function
```

ERROR:

```
Out-Excel : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and 
its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At \\util01\cs\Scripts\PowerShell\BradleyDev\Google Chrome\Set-Chrome-Service-ON-V3.ps1:52 char:14
+ } $Results | Out-Excel -Prefix "Services_Results"
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (@{PC=CD-100TRAINER; Status=OFF-LINE}:PSObject) [Out-Excel], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Out-Excel
```

---

### This works:

I wanted to be able to use the function and set a file name prefix depending on name of the results. The code below works by adding another parameter "the object" I want to pass to the function, **however I loose the ability to pipe the object to the function**. Apparently if I use $input I can not take pipeline arguments?

```
function Out-Excel {
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,HelpMessage="Enter Prefix")]
    [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
    [string[]]$Prefix = $null,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,HelpMessage="Enter Prefix")]
    [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
    [object]$Object = $null,
    $Path = "$env:temp\$Prefix`_$(Get-Date -Format yyMMdd_HHmmss).csv"
)
$Object | Export-CSV -Path $Path -UseCulture -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
Invoke-Item -Path $Path
} #end function
```

---

```
$Results +=$PCobject
 } Out-Excel -object $Results -Prefix "Services_Results"`
```

Comment: remove the `Return` keyword

Comment: That will now allow the `-Prefix "File_Name"` however now the object data is not filling out the cvs file. I believe the issue is that the function uses the $input variable `$input | Export-CSV -Path $Path -UseCulture -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: You specify that the `Prefix` parameter accepts `ValueFromPipeline`, so it is consuming your piped in data. Unless you need that there I would remove that Parameter Option.

Comment: I removed the pipline REQ's `function Out-Excel {
 param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,HelpMessage="Enter Prefix")]
     [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
     [string[]]$Prefix = $null,
        $Path = "$env:temp\$Prefix```_$(Get-Date -Format yyMMdd_HHmmss).csv"
    )
 $input | Export-CSV -Path $Path -UseCulture -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
 Invoke-Item -Path $Path
} #end function` However I still get `Out-Excel : The input object cannot be bound ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to accept pipeline input from advanced function, then it have to have parameters, which declared as `ValueFromPipeline` or `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName` and does not bound from command line.

```powershell
function Out-Excel {
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,HelpMessage="Enter Prefix")]
    [string]$Prefix = $null,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
    [psobject]$InputObject = $null,
    $Path = "$env:temp\$Prefix`_$(Get-Date -Format yyMMdd_HHmmss).csv"
)
begin{
    $List=New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[PSObject]
}
process{
    $List.Add($InputObject)
}
end{
    $List | Export-CSV -Path $Path -UseCulture -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
    Invoke-Item -Path $Path
}
} #end function
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, exactly like I wanted. Thank you petseral